# Entity Framework Does not work with foreign key interface

Tags: c#, .net

I sign my entire database model with Ientity interface,

```
   public List<TEntity> GetAll(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null)
    {
        using (TContext context = new TContext())
        {
            return filter == null ?
                context.Set<TEntity>().ToList() :
                context.Set<TEntity>().Where(filter).ToList();
        }
    }
    }

     public class Products:IEntity
    {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
           //.....
        [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
        public virtual ProductCategories ProductCategories { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    }




    public class ProductCategories: IEntity
    {

        [Key]
        [Required]
        public int ProductCatId { get; set; }

          //...
    }
```

I added db context

```
 public class EsitProductContext:DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Products> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductCategories> ProductCategories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductImage> ProductImages { get; set; }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {

            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {

                optionsBuilder
                    .UseSqlServer("...")
                    .UseLazyLoadingProxies(false);

            }
        }

    }
```

I have a layered architecture, the following code is part of the DAL layer,

```
  public class EfEntityRepositoryBase<TEntity, TContext> : IEntityRepository<TEntity>
          where TEntity : class, IEntity, new()
        where TContext : DbContext, new()
    {

     //...
  public List<TEntity> GetAll(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null)
        {
            using (TContext context = new TContext())
            {
                return filter == null ?
                    context.Set<TEntity>().ToList() :
                    context.Set<TEntity>().Where(filter).ToList();
            }
        }
   }
```

my problem is that when I use my model instead of TEntity interface, the Collection that I specified with the foreing key does not come null, but when I try to use the Entity interface, why does it come null?

```
 return context.Set<Products>().ToList(); //It works smoothly
```

Comment: This is not C code. Please remove the `C` tag unless there is some special reason for including that.

Comment: How do you call the `GetAll` method by passing a type to TEntity?

Comment: you don't need to see it because the getall function is already null inside.

watched with break point